# Navigating vuejs SPA via routes that share component does not refresh component data as expected

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a couple routes in my vuejs SPA that I have set up using vue-router:

- /create/feedback
- /edit/feedback/66a0660662674061b84e8ea2fface0e4

The component for each route is the same form with a bit of smarts to change form values based on the absence or present of the ID in the route (feedbackID, in my example).

I notice that when I click from the edit route to the create route, the data in my form does not clear.

Below is the gist of my route file

```
import FeedbackFormView    from './components/FeedbackForm.vue'

// Routes
const routes = [
    {
      path: '/create/feedback',
      component: FeedbackFormView,
      name: 'FeedbackCreate',
      meta: {
          description: 'Create Feedback',
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/edit/feedback/:feedbackId',
      component: FeedbackFormView,
      name: 'FeedbackEdit',
      meta: {
          description: 'Edit Feedback Form'
      },
      props: true
    }


   ]

export default routes
```

Below is the gist of my component

```
<template lang="html">
  <div>
      <form>
          <input v-model="model.someProperty">
      </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() => ({model: {someProperty:''}}),
    props: ['feedbackId'],
    created() => {
        if (!this.$props['feedbackId']) {
          return;
        }

        // otherwise do ajax call and populate model
        // ... details omitted
    }
}
</script>
```

However, if I modify my component as follows, everything works as expected

```
<template lang="html">
  <div>
      <form>
          <input v-model="model.someProperty">
      </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() => ({model: {someProperty:''}}),
    props: ['feedbackId'],
    created() => {
        if (!this.$props['feedbackId']) {
          return;
        }

        // otherwise do ajax call and populate model
        // ... details omitted
    },
    watch: {
      '$route' (to, from) {
        if (to.path === '/create/feedback') {
          this.model = {}
        }
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

Why is this? Why do I need *watch*?

I would have though that changing routes would be sufficient as the purpose of routing is to mimic the semantic behavior of page navigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who come this later, the following answer addresses the issue I was facing:

[Vue-Router: view returning to login page after page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42250717/vue-router-view-returning-to-login-page-after-page-refresh)

Answer (score 2):

You have same component for different routes, when you go to edit route from the create route component is already created and mounted so the state of the component doesn't clear up.

Your component can listen to route changes using `$router` provided by `vue-router` every time the route changes the watcher is called.

Comment: Yes, the behavior is as you described. As I understand them, routes are meant to mimic traditional multi-page web navigation (i.e. give the user the experience of navigating between pages). Certainly if a user clicked from edit to create, they'd expect the form to change. I had thought that a router would encapsulate this behavior. No?

Comment: No, until a different route with different component is called, @Jordan